# How do I return to a while loop from the main code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to return to a while loop after it is done.

Basically, in my main code, at the beginning, there is a while loop that I want to do for x amount of times and then exit out and execute some other code. If certain values are met, return to the while loop at the top of the main.

Here is the code that I wrote but once the while loop is finished it just stops.

```
t = 0

def main():

    global t

    try:

        while t < 3:

            distance = Tank_Measurement()
            if distance > 5 and distance < 100:                         
                print ('Distance:',distance ,'cm')
                Pumping_to_Growbed()
                time.sleep(2)
                draining_Selenoid()
                t =  t + 1    
            else:
                print ('Distance:',distance ,'cm is out of range')      
                time.sleep(1)                                         
                Tank_Measurement()
                t =  t + 1
        return

        distance = Tank_Measurement()
        distance2 = growbed_Measurement()

        if distance < 5 and distance2 < 5:
            print ('Water level in main tank low')
            print ('Filling up main tank')
            time.sleep(1)
            Pumping_to_mainTank()
            t = 0
        else:
            t = 0

    except KeyboardInterrupt:                                           

        print ('Exiting program gracefully')                            
        for i in range(3,0,-1):
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write(str(i)+' ')
            sys.stdout.flush()
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()                                                  
main()
```

Comment: The `while` loop should be extracted to its own function and called when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entire body of `main()` inside another *another* while loop:

```
def main():
    keep_looping  = True
    while keep_looping:
        ... original code here
        if some_condition:
            keep_looping = False
```

Answer (score 0):

> once the while loop is finished it just stops

That is because you have a `return` as the next statement after while. So it returns to the point where you called `main()`, which then is the last line of your code, no further statements or code after that.